# General solution for differential equation $px-qy=2xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Show that general solution of $$px-qy=2xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$ can be expressed in the form of $$z=e^{2xy}\int_0^{x+y}e^{-u^2}du+e^{-2xy}\int_0^{x+y}e^{-u^2}du+f(x,y)$$
>
> Where $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

From Lagrangian equations:

$$\frac {dx}{x}=\frac {dy}{-y}=\frac {dz}{2x e^{-(x^2+y^2)}}$$

Taking first two terms we obtain $$xy=c_1$$
Then taking second and third terms, and putting $x= \frac{c_1}{y}$ we get

$$dz+\frac{2c_1 e^{-\left(y^2+\frac{c_1^2}{y^2}\right)}}{y^2} dy= 0$$

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

Making the variables change

$$
\xi = x y\\
\eta = \frac xy
$$

we obtain

$$
\eta  u_{\eta}(\xi ,\eta )+\sqrt{\eta \xi } e^{-\frac{\left(\eta ^2+1\right) \xi }{\eta }}=0
$$

and then

$$
u(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-2 \xi } \left(\text{erf}\left(\left(\frac{1}{\eta }-1\right) \sqrt{\eta } \sqrt{\xi }\right)-e^{4 \xi }
   \text{erf}\left(\left(\frac{1}{\eta }+1\right) \sqrt{\eta } \sqrt{\xi }\right)+e^{4 \xi }-1\right)+\phi(\eta)
$$

or simplifying a little more

$$
u(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-2 \xi } \left(e^{4 \xi } \text{erfc}\left((\eta +1) \sqrt{\frac{\xi }{\eta }}\right)-\text{erfc}\left((1-\eta )
   \sqrt{\frac{\xi }{\eta }}\right)\right)+\phi(\xi)
$$

NOTE

The final integration was obtained with the MATHEMATICA command

`Integrate[-E^(-(((1 + eta^2) xi)/eta)) Sqrt[xi/eta], eta] // FullSimplify`

After recovering the original variables, this integral is equivalent to

$$
\int\frac{e^{-\frac{C_1^2}{x^2}-x^2}}{x^2}dx
$$

now as

$$
\left(\frac{C_1}{x}+x\right)^2-2C_1 = \frac{C_1^2}{x^2}+x^2
$$

the integral becomes

$$
e^{2C_1}\int\frac{e^{-\left(\frac{C_1}{x}+x\right)^2}}{x^2}dx
$$

I hope this helps.

Concerning the above integral we have that

$$
\left(\int_0^x e^{a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}+x\right)^2}\right)' = e^{a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}+x\right)^2} \left(1-\frac{c^2}{x^2}\right)\\
\left(\int_0^x e^{-a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}-x\right)^2}\right)' = -e^{-a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}+x\right)^2} \left(1+\frac{c^2}{x^2}\right)
$$

and

$$
\left(\int_0^x e^{-a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}-x\right)^2}\right)' -\left(\int_0^x e^{a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}+x\right)^2}\right)' = \frac{\left(c^2-x^2\right) e^{a-\left(\frac{c^2}{x}+x\right)^2}}{x^2}+\frac{\left(c^2+x^2\right) e^{-a-\left(x-\frac{c^2}{x}\right)^2}}{x^2}
$$

now choosing a convenient $a$ ...

Comment: sir how did u guesss this? truly amazing

Comment: Sir in step2, it should be negative sign. Can you pls elaborate on how did u get step 3 directly. I got $d\zeta / 0 = \sqrt {\frac{\eta}{\zeta}}d \eta = \frac{dz}{e^{-(\eta^2+1) \zeta / \eta}} $

Comment: I am going thru error function in wolfram.... Not able to how expression 3 came..

Comment: @Magneto The integration is not an elementary one so I used MATHEMATICA to find out a closed expression.

Comment: @Magneto Knowing that $x y=C_1$ is a characteristic curve, I made a change of variables to $\xi,\eta$ looking for a simplification. Really no guess.

Comment: But Qn is related to this integration only.  Can pls help on how to integrate this? I tried but i am not getting....

Comment: @Cesaro i tried it here to see atleast some method to integrate --> http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt(x)+e%5E%7B-a(x%2B(1%2Fx))%7D                .....

But i could not get any clue

Comment: @Cesaro i tried to integrate my expression as above(in my answer where i got struck) in wolfram , it is huge ... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2Fx%5E2)+e%5E%7B-(x%5E2%2B(a%2Fx%5E2))%7D

.........But wolfram did it? Any clue???

Comment: @Cesaro i got struck here itself. Pls see my integral in Qn. I was not able to evaluate that integral or arrive at given expression in Qn.